# Changing play/pause buttons on audio timeupdate

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html5-audio

I have a play/pause button that needs to change on timeupdate because of a history API script. This may seem pointless to change the button on timeupdate but its not, as I shall explain.

I have a history API script that enables users to go between pageloads without a full page refresh. This also allows for conitnuous play of audio between pageloads. The problem I came into was that if the user returned to the track after going somewhere else (it would still be playing in the background) the pause button would have become a play button. So to combat this I put the pause/play function into the timeupdate so it would update.

```
$(song).on('timeupdate', function() {
    //Bind body_player controls to timeupdate so updates throughout pageloads. 
     if (song.paused){
         $('.main_controls').replaceWith('<div class="main_controls" id ="play" data-t_id="' + t_id +'"></div>'); //change main controls also
         $(".body_container*[data-t_id='" + t_id +"'] .player .controls").replaceWith('<div class="controls" id="play" title="Play"></div>');   
      }
      else {
          $('.main_controls').replaceWith('<div class="main_controls" id ="pause" data-t_id="' + t_id +'"></div>'); //change main controls also
          $(".body_container*[data-t_id='" + t_id +"'] .player .controls").replaceWith('<div class="controls" id="pause" title="Pause"></div>'); 
      }
}
```

As you can see this would cause problems as the button is constantly being updated. Due to this, sometimes if the user clicks the button nothing would happen as it was being updated at the time. Other than this its incredibly inefficient to update the DOM that much. So i came up with this:

```
var i = 0;
$(song).on('timeupdate', function() {
    i++
    //Bind body_player controls to timeupdate so updates throughout pageloads. 
    if (song.paused){
    i = 0;
        $('.main_controls').replaceWith('<div class="main_controls" id ="play" data-t_id="' + t_id +'"></div>'); //change main controls also
        $(".body_container*[data-t_id='" + t_id +"'] .player .controls").replaceWith('<div class="controls" id="play" title="Play"></div>');   
    }
    else {
        if (i === 1){
            $('.main_controls').replaceWith('<div class="main_controls" id ="pause" data-t_id="' + t_id +'"></div>'); //change main controls also
            $(".body_container*[data-t_id='" + t_id +"'] .player .controls").replaceWith('<div class="controls" id="pause" title="Pause"></div>'); 
          }
     }
}
```

I hope you can see how that works, its reasonably simple. `i` updates with timeupdate and if `i` === `1` then the button will be changed. You can't use `i === 0` as the song starts playing on `i === 1` not 0. If it were `i === 0` the button would never be updated.

The problem I am having now is that the `(if song.p...){` isn't functioning properly. It seems the added `i++` has messed with the timeupdate so the time doesn't update after the user has paused the track. I am not totally sure on what is going on here but I think that is what is happening. The timeupdate function does not change on track pause or play so the whole function does not run.

**Note:** As a side note, there is a lot more code in the timeupdate function I have just removed it as it has very little to do with the matter in hand. If i thought it could affect this in any way i would have added it.

Comment: I din't really understand your purpose....what do you mean by 'The problem I came into was that if the user returned to the track after going somewhere else'

Comment: @ParthikGosar Sorry my explanation can't have been good enough. If the user plays a track and then goes to another page and then comes back to the track the pause button will no longer be showing.

Comment: do you pause the track when users goes to another page ?

Comment: I have a similar isse where the 'timeupdate' callback is not working (in Safari) when you go to another page then press the back button. Other jQuery bindings on the page still work. Any ideas how to solve this?